# What does 'a crazy idea' mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

Does it mean ***an eccentric idea*** or even ***a very interesting idea***? I referred to a number of dictionaries, but I guess I couldn't find a definition that fits this context.

> Anne Thorndike, a primary care physician at Massachusetts General
> Hospital in Boston, had ***a crazy idea***. She believed she could
> improve the eating habits of thousands of hospital staff and visitors
> without changing their willpower or motivation in the slightest way.
> In fact, she didn’t plan on talking to them at all. Thorndike and her
> colleagues designed a six-month study to alter the “choice
> architecture” of the hospital cafeteria. She started by changing how
> drinks were arranged in the room. Originally, the refrigerators
> located next to the cash registers in the cafeteria were filled with
> only soda. She added water as an option to each one. Additionally, she
> placed baskets of bottled water next to the food stations throughout
> the room. Soda was still in the primary refrigerators, but water was
> now available at all drink locations. Over the next three months, the
> number of soda sales at the hospital dropped by 11.4 percent.
> Meanwhile, sales of bottled water increased by 25.8 percent. [Atomic Habits: the life-changing million-copy #1 bestseller](https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=fFCjDQAAQBAJ&pg=PT60&lpg=PT60&dq=Anne%20Thorndike,%20a%20primary%20care%20physician%20in%20Boston,%20had%20a%20crazy%20idea.%20She%20believed%20she%20could%20improve%20the%20eating%20habits%20of%20thousands%20of%20hospital%20staff%20and%20visitors%20without%20changing&source=bl&ots=M2owfvstT3&sig=ACfU3U0r6825utKv01IdDZ3OQB712of1JQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi-hMLu1Jr4AhXYdd4KHSSyB2MQ6AF6BAgVEAM#v=onepage&q=Anne%20Thorndike%2C%20a%20primary%20care%20physician%20in%20Boston%2C%20had%20a%20crazy%20idea.%20She%20believed%20she%20could%20improve%20the%20eating%20habits%20of%20thousands%20of%20hospital%20staff%20and%20visitors%20without%20changing&f=false)

Answer (score 3):

Judging by the text you have quoted, **had a crazy idea** means **had an idea that *seemed* crazy** (stupid; not sensible) at first but actually proved to be sensible and effective.

[See this.](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/crazy_1?q=crazy)

Answer (score 0):

In this case the idea is both interesting and not really strange in a way. The idea did work though, as it applies to psychology and "illusions" to trick the brain to adopt certain habits without you realising it, or in this case buying less soda and more water. So I would call it "interesting".